# Replace nested foreach in easy way

Tags: c#, linq, loops, foreach

I have two nested **foreach** loop:

```
foreach (var item in appArray)
{
  if (item.Value == "True")
  {
    foreach (var pair in appSeedData)
    {
      if (item.Key.Contains(pair.Key))
        pair.Value();
    }
  }         
}
```

It's possbile to do the same code but with **LINQ**? Or in easiest way?

Comment: "It's possbile to do the same code but with LINQ? Or in easiest way?" - it *is*, but ... what you have is already fine IMO, and it is more efficient than LINQ would be, and it is already the "easiest way".

Comment: What makes you think, that this is "the hardest" (or less easy) way?

Comment: I'm thinking how to do it with LINQ as it's very common now...

Comment: @4est do you know what else is "very common now"? people trying to migrate perfectly good code to LINQ for no real reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Techincally, you can put a *Linq* query:

```
var actions = appArray
  .Where(item => (item.Value == "True")
  .SelectMany(item => appSeedData
    .Where(pair => item.Key.Contains(pair.Key))
    .Select(pair => pair.Value));
```

and then perform each (`Action`?) value:

```
foreach (var action in actions)
  action();
```

But I doubt if it's *more readable*; I suggest *Linq* and `foreach` *combination*:

```
foreach (var item in appArray.Where(x => x.Value == "True")))
  foreach (var pair in appSeedData.Where(p => item.Key.Contains(p.Key)))
    pair.Value();
```

Answer (score 3):

The LINQ way would be:

```cs
var values = from item in appArray
             where item.Value == "True"
             from pair in appSeedData
             where item.Key.Contains(pair.Key)
             select pair.Value;

foreach (var value in values) {...}
```

However, personally I prefer what you had already. It is clear, obvious, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible way to go with, but I agree with @Dmitry's answer.

```
appArray.Where(item => item.Value == "True").ForEach(item => 
    appSeedData.Where(pair => item.Key.Contains(pair.Key)).ForEach(pair => {
        // do work
    }));
```